# Object of class "story" could not be converted to string

Tags: php

I'm having an issue with a bit of my code; it was working fine until I added a single new function, now it's not working at all--it's sending "Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class story could not be converted to string". I've removed the function from the class, and still am getting that error.

```
    <?php
class story extends StarMap
{
    function __construct($X, $Y, $db)
    {
        $this->X = $X;
        $this->Y = $Y;
        $this->db = $db;
        parent::__construct($this->X, $this->Y, $this->db);
        #echo $this->AddStoryElement();
    }
    function AddStoryElement()
    {
        #$array = $this->selectStoryArray();
        $array = array('1');
        $top = mt_rand(0, 95);
        $left = mt_rand(0, 95);
        $html = "\n <div class='star' style='top:{$top}%; left:'{$left}%;' href='#' id='{$array[0]}'>";
        $html .= "<img src='assets/stars/unknown.png' width='25' height='25'>";
        $html .= "</div>";
        return $html;
    }
    function selectStoryArray()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT story_id, story_type, story_content, story_url FROM storymaptopdown";
        $que = $this->db->query($sql);
        try { 
        $que->execute(); 
        while($row = $que->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH))
        {
            return $row;
        }
        }catch(PDOException $e) {}

    }
}
?>
```

This is where the class is called

```
    require_once('lib/bootstrap.php');
echo    '<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>'.
        '<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>'.
        '<script src="js/hoverintent.js" type="text/javascript"></script>'.
        '<script src="js/jquery.tooltip.js" type="text/javascript"></script>'.
        '<script src="js/js.js" type="text/javascript"></script>'.
    $map = new story($_GET['X'], $_GET['Y'], $db);
    return true;
```

Comment: Please clarify what method did you add and on what line you have the error.

Comment: I think the error is not in this code, but only you can be sure of that. Can you isolate where it happens? An error message should specify a file and line number as well.

Comment: The error is in calling the class. All i did was add a $story = new story($X, $Y, $DB); to my index page and the error ensued.

Comment: @GolezTrol As i just posted above (But failed to tag anyone) the error is in calling the class. I'm calling it through normal means and it was working prior to adding the AddStoryElement() function, but even if i'm not calling the specific function anywhere in the code I'm still getting the error. I've removed said function but still getting the error.

Comment: As far as I can see, the error is not in this code. Somewhere, you are trying to use the `story` object as a string (`echo $story`, `"something" . $story`, etc). That will not work.

Comment: Thanks for posting the calling code as well. And there's your answer as well. See how it helps? ;-)

Comment: @GolezTrol I thought i posted it in the first place, my bad! lol I was going a bit crazy trying to figure out why the class wasn't working!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are concatenating the result of the `$map = new story()` line to the previous string (the one starting with the `echo`). You probably meant to put a `;` there not an `.`.

Or if you did wanted to concatenate it, define the magic [`__toString()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) method on your class.

Comment: Ah! That would be it!... though i suppose that means i deleted a line somewhere in here. thank you! I feel stupid now